# :subclasses Replacement in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Right now I have:

```
  @models = ActiveRecord::Base.send(:subclasses)
```

But I get this in the log:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: subclasses is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 3.0 (use descendants instead). (called from send at /Users/*******/m3p0/app/controllers/roles_controller.rb:50)
```

What should I replace `:subclasses` with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is in the warning, it says use descendants instead.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.send(:descendants)
```

Also, these methods are publicly available so you don't need to use the .send syntax, you can call it explicitly.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.descendants
```

Here is the output from one of my apps:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > ActiveRecord::Base.subclasses
 => [Achievement(id: integer... 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :003 >   ActiveRecord::Base.descendants
 => [Achievement(id: integer...
```